# How to load custom fonts having huge size in ios

Tags: ios, fonts, uitextview, custom-font

I am trying to apply a custom font of **4MB** `ttf` file size.

When I am trying to load the font programmatically it is applying to text in textview it is taking too much to apply.

I tried to apply on background thread and also on main thread. But the time taking to apply to textview in same.

How can I load it fast and apply to textview.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineheight-2;
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = lineheight-2;
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = lineheight-2;

NSString *string = desc.text;
NSDictionary *ats = @{
                       NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:descsize],
                       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0f/255.0f green:85.0f/255.0f blue:85.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0],
                     };

desc.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:ats];
```

Comment: Why is the font so big?

Comment: as per the client requirement we need to use that font which is supporting multiple languages.

Comment: But they have already done android app with same font. And there is no problem in android

Comment: Show the code for how you're using the font and setting the text.

Comment: @Wain i have edited my query with the code i am using...

Comment: Have you tried splitting the font into several subsets, for different languages?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 
No. I didn't tried.
But when I asked to client they said it is not possible for this font and have to use the same font without any change

Comment: Can you add more details with some timing? How long does styling English or Cyrillic take with a small font, versus English or Cyrillic with this big font, versus Japanese or Chinese with this big font? (basically: can you show us that you've done some debugging that clearly demonstrates it's this font, and not something else)

Comment: But we are from India. And we do have lot of regional languages here. Ex: Telugu, Hindi, Tamil, Malayalam, Kannada, Oriya, Gujarathi, Punjabi, etc...
Totally the font consists of 18 languages.